# E text-editor shortcut for commenting out code?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, comments, e-texteditor

Anyone happens to know what is the shortcut for comment out the code in E text-editor??

Answer (score 1):

Select the block, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> should do the job for most languages.

Answer (score -1):

As this is the first result on Google and there's no answer, I thought I'd at least mention that at 27/03/10 that the [official cheat sheet on their Wiki](http://www.e-texteditor.com/wiki/index.php/Cheatsheet) shows no such function.

Comment: No foul language, please.